# Abelian subgroup but not cyclic

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Is there $G$ subgroup of $S_n$ that is abelian but not cyclic?

I found: $G=\left\{id,\left(2\:3\right)\left(1\:4\right),\left(2\:4\right)\left(1\:3\right),\left(3\:4\right)\left(1\:2\right)\right\}$

It is right? And there is maybe an easier example?

Comment: Considering that the smallest noncyclic abelian group has four elements, it's hard to see how there could be a simpler example. Well, you could take $\{1,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right.   You found the copy of the Klein four subgroup in $S_4$ which is normal.   There are $3$ others which are not normal.

Since $S_4\hookrightarrow S_{4+k} $, this example will "work" for any $n\ge4$ (but without the normality property ).

You could also use Cayley's theorem to embed *any* finite, noncyclic abelian group in some  $S_n $.